# How to parse a string with variables into a react component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have  a string with a variable inside:

```
var template = '<div>Hello {username}</div>';
```

The username is set by the state, how to parse this string and turn it into a react component?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't just using jsx instead of a string? `var template = <div>Hello {username}</div>` works right out of the box without anything fancy

Comment: I have the HTML in separate files, work policy, designers are not allowed to change js files, just HTML files

Comment: the question was already asked and [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33342686/7049654)

Comment: I'm using babel.transform('<div>hello</div>').code but get an error 'Unexpected token', also "import babel from 'babel-core';" generates an error "TypeError: isNaN is not a function", looks like it doesn't play nice with my meteor + redux +react app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `RegExp` to identify all `{}` sets. Then, replace the value with the state value and update the string. Finally use [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)
to insert the HTML string into react node. See the example.

Hope this helps!

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      username: 'Pranesh',
      userId: 124,
    }
  }
  render(){
    var template = '<div>Hello {username}. Your user id is {userId}.</div>';
    var r = template.match(/\{[\w]+\}/g);
    r && r.forEach((state) => {
      var regex = new RegExp(state, 'g')
      var stateItem = state.split(/{|}/g)[1]
      template  = template.replace(regex, this.state[stateItem])
    })
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: template}}/> 
    
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but you can do var `template = (<div>{this.state.username}</div>)`

Comment: the problem is that the string comes from a html file using fs.read