# How to render jsx stored as a string in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, eval, render

I am trying to build a react app with customized components. The input to the app is a jsx(as a string) coming from an API.
Now i want to render this input jsx (a string variable), but not able to do that. I have tried eval() and dangerouslySetInnerHTML options, but it did not work out.
My JSX String looks like

```html
'<div> <MyComponent attr_1={this.state.array["field"]}></MyComponent> </div>'
```

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is the way to do this. Please show how you're trying to do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render a string with JSX in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262702/how-to-render-a-string-with-jsx-in-react)

Comment: @jayce444 "  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: str}}></div> );"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I figured out JsxParser is the right way of solving my problem.
[react-jsx-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-jsx-parser) provides capability to parser and render react component from JSX string.